# Loop with apache camel

Tags: xpath, xml-parsing, apache-camel

I am expecting multiple operation in one request. I need to to loop the xml to to do the following using Apache camel route.
1) get the total opertions in request xml and put in variable.
2) get total number of expression using xpath on xml and put in list
3) loop with (total number of operation ) times to evaluate the expression

First step would be  list nodeList = /tractscation/operations

```
<loop>
<constant>nodeLIst.length</xpath>
compare and execute operation
</loop>
```

Above lines are just psuedo code, i want anybody help me with exact code using camel Xpath and loop. .

I am new to xpath and camel. we are using camelxpath spring DSL

Comment: I suggest to read about the EIPs Camel support: http://camel.apache.org/eip

Answer (score 0):

if you want to loop through each node matching the xpath and process it individually, then use [camel-splitter](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) EIP...

```
<route>
    <from uri="direct:a"/>
    <split>
        <xpath>/transaction/operations</xpath>
        <to uri="direct:b"/>
    </split>
</route>
```

otherwise, there is a [camel-loop](http://camel.apache.org/loop.html) EIP that can be used to execute the same process a variable number of times...but the splitter is generally used for parsing/looping type of operations

```
from("direct:c").loop().xpath("/hello/@times").to("mock:result");
```

Comment: Thank you  very much.  I need to process each node and route them to different processor. Something like dynamic routing by processing the node type and accordingly route each of them to different destination. Could you please give me idea of any sort of small architecture i can write to achieve seamless integration

Comment: I used like  <split><toeknizer/> using xpath to traverse the beans </split>. Now i want to combine the response of both beans which it seems, i have to use aggregator..can anybdy plz help in this.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps you =D

Inside route

```
    <to uri="direct:WSCall" />

    <split strategyRef="groupExchangeAggregationStrategy">
          <xpath>//response/operation</xpath>
    </split>
```

Velocity template

```
<tag>
   #foreach( $exchangeItem in ${body} )
      ${exchangeItem.in.body}
   #end
</tag>
```

Include

```
<beans>
  <bean id="groupExchangeAggregationStrategy" class="org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy" />
</beans>
```